# Android - Displaying data on cardview from firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-cardview

I am trying to display my data from my database on a Cardview. It is working but instead of displaying the data on individual cards, all data is grouped together in one card. What could be the reason for this?

This is how my Firebase database looks:[image: Firebase]

This is how it looks:

[image]

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Card.xml (layout file)

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Fragment class:

```
public class HistoryFragment extends Fragment {

RecyclerView recyclerView;
DatabaseReference myRef;
FirebaseAuth mAuth;


@Override

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_history, container, false);

    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    final FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();


    myRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(user.getDisplayName());

    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));

    FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Bet, BetViewHolder> adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Bet, BetViewHolder>(
            Bet.class,
            R.layout.history_individual_row,
            BetViewHolder.class,
            myRef
    ) {
        @Override
        protected void populateViewHolder(BetViewHolder viewHolder, Bet model, int position) {
            viewHolder.setTextDescription(model.desc());
            viewHolder.setTitle(model.title());
            viewHolder.setTextFlow(model.flow());
        }
    };

    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);


    return rootView;
}

public static class BetViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView text1View, text2View, text3View;

    public BetViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        text1View= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.text1);
        text2View= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.text2);
        text3View= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.text3);
    }

    public void setTextDescription(String desc) {
        text1View.setText(desc);
    }


    public void setTitle(String title) {
        text2View.setText(title);
    }

    public void setTextFlow(String flow) {
        text3View.setText(flow);

    }
}

}
```

Comment: Can you add your layout file, and code with displaying data, please ?

Comment: Yes, I have edited my question with the code

Answer (score 0):

I think problem is in your firebase json format - you store *not array of elements*, you store a  a one big object (user) with multiple children fields, so it returns to you all your objects as a one big object.

I have had the same problem before, so that's why I highly recommend you to find something else that firebase, which is (in my opinion) not right way to store complicated objects (like with one-to-many relationships or inner arrays, as you wanna have), because it has not database actually, it just saves your json.

In addition, it doesn't let you to implement any type of search or querying.

So, my answer is: the reason I firebase, change it to the normal server with the normal sql (or noSql) database.

Comment: Firebase is a noSql database